# Authentication Swagger with JWT Bearer token

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, token, swagger

We are developing a .Net Core 2.1 Web API with JWT Bearer authentication. The application itself will generate and hand out tokens which are to be send to the backend.

While we have everything up and running, i.e. we can send the bearer token from Angular and test it with Postman, Swagger won't send the Bearer token. 
We have added the Swagger configuration to use a SecurityDefinition as followed, I will post the complete ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                policy => policy.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
        });
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAllOrigins"));
        });

        ServiceInstaller.Install(services, Configuration);

        // api user claim policy
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            var authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            options.AddPolicy("Bearer", authorizationPolicy);
        });
        // add identity
        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
        {
            // configure identity options
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        });
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var keyByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("placekeyhere");
        var signingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);
        services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; }).AddJwtBearer(
            options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                    ValidAudience = "Audience",
                    ValidIssuer = "Issuer",
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
                };
            });
        // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = "Issuer";
            options.Audience = "Audience";
            options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        });

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "AppName", Version = "v1" });
            c.OperationFilter<UploadOperation>();
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Authorization", new ApiKeyScheme
            {
                Description =
                    "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header",
                Type = "apiKey",
            });
        });
    }
```

This does add the Authenticate option to the top of the screen. In the configure method we tell the application to actually use the authentication:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseSwagger();
            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AppName"); });
        }
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

However when we authenticate ourselves with a token, the curl for the function does not show the Bearer token. It looks like Swagger does not send the token to the backend.

We use .Net Core 2.1 and Swagger 2.3. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you accept my answer if it helped ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update - The Swagger spec has changed. check answer by @nilay below for the correct solution.**

I had the very same problem.

2 things are neccessary

1. You have to put `"bearer <token-here>"` like this.
   Putting only token will not work.
2. 

to get this to work in swagger 2.x, you need to accompany your scheme definition with a corresponding requirement to indicate that the scheme is applicable to all operations in your API:

```
c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    { "Bearer", new string[] { } }
});
```

Complete definition:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Some API", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme()
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = "header",
                    Type = "apiKey"
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "Bearer", new string[] { } }
                });
            });
```

Comment: it would be extra help someone could add an explanation.

Comment: It seems pretty self explanatory to me. By adding security requirement you are telling swagger that he should use Bearer scheme for all operations. And he will use it.

Comment: As per the Swagger spec https://swagger.io/specification/#securityRequirementObject, defining the scheme alone is not sufficient. You also need to provide a Security Requirement Object at the document level or on individual operations to indicate which operations that scheme is applicable to.

Comment: Still I am getting unauthorized. I have added the value as step num 1 and still unable to access the authorized actions. Can you help me out with further details.
Using .net core 2.1 web api

Answer (score 6):

I also face same issue, but I am using new version of Swagger which is based on OpenAPI. So, I have to use below snippet for same.

```
var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
{
    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
    Name = "Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    Scheme = "bearer",
    BearerFormat = "JWT"
};

var securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "bearerAuth"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
    }
};

options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", securityScheme);
options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirement);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer now.  Just as a note, Scheme must be lowercase ('bearer').  If you use JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme (which is 'Bearer'), it will not work.

Comment: Yes, I had faced this issue. :(  Then came to know that there is also case change of `bearer` between OpenApi & Swagger's Api.